# can we add image in awt Frames in java?

Tags: java, awt, frame

in JFrame imageIcon is used but in frame what we can use to add image to frame? Can we attach image in awt label in Frame?

Comment: in awt frames i cant able to add image.but in JFrame i know how to add image.even when i take JLabel in frames ,i can able to add image to Jlabel.But in simple frames i dont know the code to add image or said to be background image..please help and tell me the code

Comment: You're still not telling us **why AWT and not Swing**. And please don't beg for code as you should always first show what you've tried and tell how/why it's not working.

Comment: because i am a lecturer and students ask me that can we add image to frame or background image in a frame.Now if u have code tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Change myImage.jpg to image that you want. Make sure this image locate at same location with this source file.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Test extends Frame {
    ImageIcon a;

    WindowListener wl = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    public Test() {
        a = new ImageIcon("myImage.jpg");
        setSize(a.getIconWidth(), a.getIconHeight());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addWindowListener(wl);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test myTest = new Test();
    }
}
```

Source(s):
http://java2everyone.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

just set an imagIcon on a new JLabel and add this new JLabel where you want in your frame.

Comment: His question is regarding AWT, not Swing. I'm still trying to find out why, but until we know, your answer is wrong.